# why can Timedeltas can be subtracted but not added

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe df containing timedelta values

```
Index     Time
0        2020-04-20 13:02:28.783
1        2020-04-20 13:02:29.713
```

I can perform the subtraction operation successfully

```
 diff  = df['Time'][1] - df['Time'][0]

 print(diff)
 0 days 00:00:00.930000
```

But the addition operation

```
 sum  = df['Time'][1] + df['Time'][0]
```

gives error

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'Timestamp'

Comment: The name 'Timedelta' already tells you which is the intended arithmetic operation: by its meaning, a delta is a difference, i.e. the result of a subtraction. However, I ***could*** imagine cases where you might want to add timestamps - you have to convert them to a float/int representation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you are adding timestamps not timedeltas. Subtracting two datetimes makes sense as you can get how many days, hours, minutes, etc are between the two timestamps. But adding timestamps has no predefined meaning, what is April 23 + April 24 supposed to mean?

If you were to subtract your minimum Time from all rows in your dataframe, then you will have timedeltas that are relative to your minimum (potentially start) time. And from there you can add and subtract as you please